# Update mysql table with data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query and I would like to make it so if there's a duplicate key it updates the values

```
INSERT INTO totalData (pageId, dateScanned, totalPageLikes, totalTalkingAbout, totalPos, totalNeg, totalFemales, totalMales, totalStrongPositives, totalPositives, totalWeakPositives, totalNeutrals, totalWeakNegatives, totalNegatives, totalStrongNegatives, totalStatuses, totalStatusLikes, totalStatusShares, totalComments, totalUniqueCommenters)

SELECT pages.pageId, pages.dateScanned, pages.likes, pages.talkingAbout,

SUM(commentTags.tag LIKE '%positive%')   AS positive, 
SUM(commentTags.tag LIKE '%negative%')   AS negative,

SUM(comments.gender = 'female')          AS females,
SUM(comments.gender = 'male')            AS males,

SUM(commentTags.tag = 'strong_positive') AS strongPositives,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'positive')    AS positives,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'weak_positive')   AS weakPositives,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'neutral')         AS neutrals,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'weak_negative')   AS weakNegatives,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'negative')    AS negatives,
SUM(commentTags.tag = 'strong_negative') AS strongNegatives,

COUNT(DISTINCT statuses.statusId)    AS totalStatuses,
SUM(DISTINCT statuses.likesCount)    AS totalLikesCount,
SUM(DISTINCT statuses.sharesCount)       AS totalSharesCount,
COUNT(DISTINCT comments.commentId)   AS totalComments,
COUNT(DISTINCT comments.userName)        AS uniqueUsers

FROM pages
JOIN statuses ON pages.pageId = statuses.pageId AND pages.dateScanned = statuses.dateScanned
JOIN comments ON comments.statusID = statuses.statusId
JOIN commentTags ON comments.commentId = commentTags.commentId

WHERE pages.pageId = '115798033817' AND pages.dateScanned = '2013-11-05'
```

I tried the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and this is how I further modified the query

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
totalData.pageId = pageId, totalData.dateScanned = dateScanned, 
totalData.totalPageLikes = totalPageLikes, totalData.totalTalkingAbout = totalTalkingAbout,
totalData.totalPos = positive, totalData.totalNeg = negative, totalData.totalFemales = females, 
totalData.totalMales = males, totalData.totalStrongPositives = strongPositives, 
totalData.totalPositives = positives, totalData.totalWeakPositives = weakPositives, 
totalData.totalNeutrals = neutrals, totalData.totalWeakNegatives = weakNegatives, 
totalData.totalNegatives = negatives, totalData.totalStrongNegatives = strongNegatives, 
totalData.totalStatuses = totalStatuses, totalData.totalStatusLikes = totalLikesCount, 
totalData.totalStatusShares = totalSharesCount, totalData.totalComments = totalComments, 
totalData.totalUniqueCommenters = uniqueUsers ;
```

But when i run the query it says `Unknown column 'positive'` in field list.

Comment: And your problem is.. ?

Comment: At the end of my post ... "But when i run the query it says Unknown column 'positive' in field list." ... How to fix this?

Comment: Error message is very clear.. "positive" column does not exist.

Comment: Can you check the query if it's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I had to use the `VALUES()` function so the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part of the query becomes like the following

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                        totalPageLikes = VALUES(totalPageLikes), totalTalkingAbout = VALUES(totalTalkingAbout), 
                        totalPos = VALUES(totalPos), totalNeg = VALUES(totalNeg), totalFemales = VALUES(totalFemales), totalMales = VALUES(totalMales), 
                        totalStrongPositives = VALUES(totalStrongPositives), totalPositives = VALUES(totalPositives), totalWeakPositives = VALUES(totalWeakPositives), 
                        totalNeutrals = VALUES(totalNeutrals), totalWeakNegatives = VALUES(totalWeakNegatives), totalNegatives = VALUES(totalNegatives), totalStrongNegatives = VALUES(totalStrongNegatives), 
                        totalStatuses = VALUES(totalStatuses), totalStatusLikes = VALUES(totalStatusLikes), totalStatusShares = VALUES(totalStatusShares), 
                        totalComments = VALUES(totalComments), totalUniqueCommenters = VALUES(totalUniqueCommenters) ";
```